# Were the domesticated animals created domesticated or wild?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, animals, parashat-bereishit

> "וַיִּצֶר ה"א מִן־הָאֲדָמָה כָּל־חַיַּת הַשָּׂדֶה וְאֵת כָּל־עוֹף הַשָּׁמַיִם"
>
> "And the LORD God formed out of the earth
> all the **wild beasts** and
> all the **birds of the sky**..." [Bereishis 2,19](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.2.19?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=he):

The English translation is very exact as Onkelos also says "כָּל חַיַּת בָּרָא וְיָת כָּל עוֹפָא דִּשְׁמַיָּא". Seemingly no cattle and small cattle and poultry were created in the process of the creation.

otherwise, why would the Torah need to add extra words השדה and השמים to designate that only the wild animals were created then?

Can this verse serve as proof that the animals were domesticated?

Comment: Animals were domesticated by humans. Adam couldn’t eat meat (post-sin, anyway); what need would he have for domesticating animals?

Comment: @DonielF how about drinking milk? using their skins? using them to work in the field? eat eggs?

Comment: Tools for plowing the field weren't invented until Noach's time (Rashi to Bereishis 5:29), so I doubt he would have used animals for working the field (otherwise, what was Noach inventing?). Hevel had a flock of sheep, so I imagine he would have used their produce; however, that occurred "after some time." For all we know, Hevel domesticated them, but for all we know, they might have already been domesticated.

Comment: 1. There were nonwild animals too. For example, [the next _pasuk_](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.2.19) makes reference to the "בהמה", which אונקלוס does not translate as wild.